# OpenVAS in windows7

Tags: security, windows-7, openvas

Is it possible to install OpenVAS in Windows 7.
If yes please tell how do I install it.

Up until now all I was able to install is client provided by greenbone, so is there any possibility to install OpenVAS server.

Thanks 
Any help and suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Natively not. Maybe if you do some experience with cygwin(https://www.cygwin.com/) and make multiple changes in openvas source code to run specifically for windows, such as / or \ or other paths, but still, I think it will be laborious. I do not know to determine, but worth a try if you have time and documenting, communicating the project is successful.